# Xamarin Forms Localization in code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization, multilingual, code-behind

I've implemented from [here](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin) and followed instructions.
It works only in xaml with

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}"  />
```

But I need it in my code behind:

```
 Label selectLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "{i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}",
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };
```

Output for that label is: {i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}.
Is there any workaround?

**UPDATE:**
As requested, I added my code (code behind and xaml pages). If you need something more please tell me.
I've just uploaded xamarin to the latest version, and I have still the same problem.

My xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyProj.Forms.Pages.TestPages.ChangeLanguagePage"
         xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:MyProj.Forms.Helpers"
         Title="{i18n:Translate ChangeLanguage}">>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label   Text="{i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}"  />
        <Picker x:Name="picker" />
        <Button Text="{i18n:Translate Save}" Clicked="OnUpdateLangugeClicked" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My code behind page:

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ChangeLanguagePage : ContentPage
{
    Picker picker;
    public ChangeLanguagePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StackLayout main = new StackLayout();

        Label selectLabel = new Label
        {
            //Text = "Select Language",
            Text = "{i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}",
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };

        picker = new Picker();

        Button btn = new Button
        {
            Text = "SAVE",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black
        };
        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;
        picker.Items.Add("English");
        picker.Items.Add("Spanish");
        picker.Items.Add("Portuguese");
        picker.Items.Add("French");
        picker.SelectedItem = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo.EnglishName;

        main.Children.Add(selectLabel);
        main.Children.Add(picker);
        main.Children.Add(btn);

        Content = main;
    }

    private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo = CrossMultilingual.Current.NeutralCultureInfoList.ToList().First(element => element.EnglishName.Contains(picker.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        AppResources.Culture = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo;
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }

    void OnUpdateLangugeClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo = CrossMultilingual.Current.NeutralCultureInfoList.ToList().First(element => element.EnglishName.Contains(picker.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        AppResources.Culture = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo;
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());

    }
}
```

Comment: it should work a same

Comment: It should, but it doesn't :)

Comment: try to use string.format

Comment: @MikeDarwish can you give me a line of code please? Like ` string fullString = "{i18n:Translate SelectLanguage}"; string.Format({0}, fullString)`

Comment: could you please add the output for both xaml and code behind, i need to check the diffrent between them

Comment: make sure you have the latest version of xamarin.forms

Comment: @MikeDarwish I've just updated xamarin.forms. Please my updated post. Thanks

Comment: Update xamarin should work fine for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **There is no code-equivalent, the services are only available via XAML**

But you can easily replace it.

```
const string ResourceId = "$rootnamespace$.AppResources";
var resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId,typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));        
var ci = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo;
Label selectLabel = new Label
{
  Text = resmgr.GetString("SelectLanguage",ci),
  TextColor = Color.Black
};
```

Remember to replace `$rootnamespace$` with your project namespace.

> https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin/blob/master/content/TranslateExtension.txt.pp

Comment: thanks, but variable resmgr doesnt have a Value property? Could you please include references just to be sure?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I remove the Lazy wrapper.

Comment: That's it! So, basically I need to put this in each class, or in ContentPage subclass in order to make to work it on all pages?

Comment: I recommend you move to a class and handle just one reference of the ResourceManager (maybe in a static field) to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text = Resx.LocalizedString.SelectLanguage,
```

I'm surprised that others say what you said is fine and should be working.

I didn't know that. Anyway, you can use it like that when you use it in code.

Comment: actually the question was not clear.. i deleted my answer

Comment: Ah, After I read a question again, I guess this is not he's looking for.